# Can you help me define parts of the sentence in these sentences?

Tags: ellipsis, existentials, exclamatives

Some of them don't even have predicates. I simply don't understand how to distinguish parts of speech here.

> 1. What a still perfect day!
> 2. No sound! A lovely evening. Then the first stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elliptic sentences, i.e. parts that are self-evident are omitted.

1 Exclamation. What a still perfect day (it is)!

2 (There is) no sound.

3 (It is) a lovely evening.

4 Then the first stars (are coming up/ are to be seen).

Subject in 1:it. In 2: no sound ( my view; there are other views.).
In 3: It. In 4: the first stars.